# SQL Ifelse by Group

Tags: sql, mysql, if-statement, group-by, datagrip

I have SQL table such as this:

```
TABLE1
STUDENT SCORE   SCOREVAL
1   PASS    10
1   MOD1    4
1   MOD2    5
2   MOD1    4
3   MOD2    2
3   MOD2    1
3   MOD1    9
3   ER  1
4   MOD2    10
4   ER  6
```

I wish to simplify table to this

```
STUDENT SCORE
STUDENT SCORE   SCOREVAL
1   PASS    10
2   MOD1    4
3   PASS    11
4   MOD2    10
```

using the rules

```
For each STUDENT
if any value of **SCORE** equals to PASS, then is PASS
if contains value MOD1 and MOD2, then is PASS
if contains value MOD1, then is MOD1
if contains value MOD2, then is MOD2
```

Then for **SCOREVAL**,

```
if any value of SCORE equals to PASS, then take MAX(SCOREVAL[SCORE = PASS])
if contains value MOD1 and MOD2, then take MAX(SCOREVAL[SCORE = MOD1] + MAX(SCOREVAL[SCORE=MOD2])
if contains value MOD1, then take MAX(SCOREVAL[SCORE = MOD1])
if contains value MOD2, then take MAX(SCOREVAL[SCORE = MOD2])
```

I try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
GROUP BY STUDENT when SCORE = 'PASS' then 'PASS'
when SCORE = 'MOD1' and SCORE = 'MOD2' then 'PASS'
when SCORE = 'MOD1' then 'MOD1'
when SCORE = 'MOD2' then 'MOD2'
else EXEMPT
end
```

without success

Comment: Can you please add a tag for the DBMS you're using, e.g. `postgresql`, or `sql-server`?

Comment: you are missing `, CASE `

Comment: @nbk can you please assist ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed the code so that the SQL query groups the data by `STUDENT`, then determines each student's final `SCORE` and `SCOREVAL` based on specific conditions using `CASE` statements and aggregate functions like `MAX()`. Hope it helps!

```
SELECT 
    STUDENT, 
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(SCORE = 'PASS') = 1 THEN 'PASS'
        WHEN MAX(SCORE = 'MOD1') = 1 AND MAX(SCORE = 'MOD2') = 1 THEN 'PASS'
        WHEN MAX(SCORE = 'MOD1') = 1 THEN 'MOD1'
        WHEN MAX(SCORE = 'MOD2') = 1 THEN 'MOD2'
        ELSE 'EXEMPT'
    END AS SCORE,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(SCORE = 'PASS') = 1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN SCORE = 'PASS' THEN SCOREVAL END)
        WHEN MAX(SCORE = 'MOD1') = 1 AND MAX(SCORE = 'MOD2') = 1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN SCORE = 'MOD1' THEN SCOREVAL END) + MAX(CASE WHEN SCORE = 'MOD2' THEN SCOREVAL END)
        WHEN MAX(SCORE = 'MOD1') = 1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN SCORE = 'MOD1' THEN SCOREVAL END)
        WHEN MAX(SCORE = 'MOD2') = 1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN SCORE = 'MOD2' THEN SCOREVAL END)
    END AS SCOREVAL
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY STUDENT;
```

Comment: what if you wish to check across multiple columns in a table? this code work perfect but what if I have columns 'SCORE1', 'SCORE2', 'SCORE3' and so on? i try to modify but I do so without succes

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't ever want `NULL` values in the `SCOREVAL` column of your result set, you can consolidate some rules and build other rules into score calculations.

For example, if there is no `PASS` entry, then you can unconditionally sum the relative max scores for `MOD1` and `MOD2` entries.  Coalesce any missing values to `0` to prevent a `NULL` value interfering with another valid entry.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
    STUDENT INT,
    SCORE TEXT,
    SCOREVAL INT
);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES
(1, 'PASS', 10),
(1, 'MOD1', 4),
(1, 'MOD2', 5),
(2, 'MOD1', 4),
(3, 'MOD2', 2),
(3, 'MOD2', 1),
(3, 'MOD1', 9),
(3, 'ER', 1),
(4, 'MOD2', 10),
(4, 'ER', 6),
(5, 'ER', 3),
(6, 'PASS', 8),
(6, 'PASS', 13),
(6, 'PASS', 7);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    STUDENT, 
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(SCORE = 'PASS') OR (MAX(SCORE = 'MOD1') AND MAX(SCORE = 'MOD2'))
            THEN 'PASS'
        WHEN MAX(SCORE = 'MOD1')
            THEN 'MOD1'
        WHEN MAX(SCORE = 'MOD2')
            THEN 'MOD2'
        ELSE
            'EXEMPT'
    END AS SCORE,
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(SCORE = 'PASS')
            THEN MAX(CASE WHEN SCORE = 'PASS' THEN SCOREVAL END)
        ELSE
            COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN SCORE = 'MOD1' THEN SCOREVAL END),0)
            + COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN SCORE = 'MOD2' THEN SCOREVAL END),0)
    END AS SCOREVAL
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY STUDENT;
```

| STUDENT | SCORE | SCOREVAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PASS | 10 |
| 2 | MOD1 | 4 |
| 3 | PASS | 11 |
| 4 | MOD2 | 10 |
| 5 | EXEMPT | 0 |
| 6 | PASS | 13 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qd2QuuQTzvSuTEJfV7ebsb/1)

Comment: what if you wish to check across multiple columns in a table? this code work perfect but what if I have columns 'SCORE1', 'SCORE2', 'SCORE3' and so on? i try to modify but I do so without succes

Comment: Please modify the demo that I've created and clarify what your extended requirements are.  Ideally, you should be asking a new question instead of extending this one.